# Allocating array of std::vector Slows Down Subsequent Computation

Tags: c++, vector

I was optimizing an algorithm.  I ran into a strange oddity.

The following:

```
//The following is completely unused
vector<int>** rotated_squares;
rotated_squares = new vector<int>*[31];
for (int i=0;i<31;++i) {
    rotated_squares[i] = new vector<int>[31];
}

{
    //Lots of computation, using other vectors, but not rotated_squares
}
```

. . . is at least ten times slower than:

```
{
    //The exact same computation as above.
}
```

I have no idea what could be causing this. The only thing I can think of is that it is an artifact of the underlying implementation somehow.  To that end, using Visual Studio 2010 for C++ compiler.

EDIT: Clarification, the computation below is the part that becomes slower.  The memory allocations at the top are almost negligible when profiling.

So the issue is that I add the lines at the top, and the code runs about ten times slower.  By debugging, the extra memory allocation takes a fraction of a second, but the computation code, which normally takes about eight seconds, starts to take several minutes.

EDIT: By popular demand, the source of the algorithm can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Yf78gTNC.  The point is that the #if 1 can be set or unset and the code compiles fine--but with it, it runs much slower in the computation section.

EDIT: I have reduced the code to the following: http://pastebin.com/mpnPsQE1.  In my code, this causes the problem.  However, making a simple test case (i.e. a main function with just this code) does *not* show the problem.

Comment: Allocating memory can be a very slow operation.

Comment: What is Vec2? Does it make a difference to put `size2[1]` instead of just `31`? And what does "The exact same computation as above" mean?

Comment: "The exact same computation as above" means identical code.  Clarified the problem--the computation code gets slower--it's not slower purely due to the memory allocation.  No difference substituting size2[n] with its value 31.  Vec2 is a custom type--problem still occurs when using "int" instead.

Comment: You obviously know about `std::vector<>`, so why are you using `new T[]`?

Comment: I suppose vector<vector<vector<int>>> looked bad.  Doesn't matter; I just tried it and got the same issue.

Comment: I was going to say that allocating 961 `vector<int>`s might push other data out of cache, but that won't cause something to go from 8s to several minutes.  That's nuts...  Is it possible that you have some debugging mode turned on?  In that case, it might be that the computation block is doing lots of allocation/deallocation of its own, and that each such call there might (in the course of some kind of debug checking) be walking through all the memory blocks already allocated.

Comment: Thanks for pasting the code, but please paste the *smallest compilable subset that reproduces the behaviour*, so we can see e.g. what the values of `size2[]` are.

Comment: I'm surprised `vector<const Vec2>` compiles at all, since `const` types are not Assignable.  (I see Alf mentions that this is UB for the 03 standard, that sounds right to me though I couldn't be sure.)

Comment: Added some test code.  In my program, it shows the problem.  However, outside, in a test case, it does not.  What could be causing that?

Comment: @IanMallett: Obviously I wasn't clear: what we need to see is *that other code* -- otherwise how will we be able to figure out what the problem is?!

Comment: @IanMallett: Also, it's a good idea to include e.g. "@j_random_hacker" in your comment if you want me to be notified.  (Only works for a single username unfortunately.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C+++03 and a `std::vector< T const >` you've passed into Undefined Behavior land. I am not sure of the situation with C++11, even after using like 10 minutes trawling the standard. But possibly the same, and in that case no special explanation is needed.

However, it might be that the code that you haven't shown, and that's allegedly slowing down, is referencing `rotated_squares`.

It might also be that the added code causes a cache miss.

It's rather difficult to reproduce without the code, but it just might help to put the slowed-down code in its own function.

Engaging ESP circuit overdrive… Concentrating… Nope, that didn't work either.

Comment: Code posted.  Also tried putting code in its own function (didn't help).  I had considered cache coherency issues, but I'm not sure how such a thing would happen.  The computation runs a comparatively long time.  Any cache miss that happens would be a one-off thing.  If rotated_squares were in the cache, then it would be removed immediately on a single cache miss, and then never cause problems again.

Answer (score 3):

> I have no idea what could be causing this.

The

```
vector<const Vec2>** rotated_squares;
rotated_squares = new vector<const Vec2>*[size2[1]]; //size2[1]==31
for (int i=0;i<size2[1];++i) {
    rotated_squares[i] = new vector<const Vec2>[size2[0]]; //size2[0]==31
}
```

part.

Comment: Question clarified.  By debugging, I see that the memory allocation takes next to no time, but the computation below somehow starts taking LOTS more time.

Comment: @IanMallett in that case, it's good that you didn't show us the code that is actually causing the problem, but code that you say makes no difference. </sarcasm>

Comment: Serious Question: How can code that has no side effect (e.g. allocating a vector of ints) cause a slowdown later?  Either something weird is happening with memory (I doubt cache coherency could be the issue) or there *is* a side effect outside of my code happening in the std::vector class.  Either way, my actual computation is irrelevant, yes?

Comment: @IanMallett It's clearly not irrelevant. If it is, you can replace it with a simple `cout` and I doubt that would be 10 times slower with the allocation. Narrow it down and post the code.

Comment: @Ian - re: "How can code that has no side effect (e.g. allocating a vector of ints)" - but that code **does** have a side effect: it **allocates** a vector of ints. Sometimes corrupting the free store can make programs run very slowly because the data they see doesn't satisfy the program's invariants and the program runs off into long, irrelevant loops. If some piece of code is messing up the free store, adding or removing otherwise irrelevant allocations changes the layout of the free store and can change the behavior of the program. These things are **nasty** to debug.